# Cauchy problem for parabolic equation

Tags: maximum-principle, parabolic-pde, cauchy-problem

Let $\mathcal{L}=a \partial_{xx}+b\partial_{x}+c$, where $a>0,c\in\mathbb{R},b\in \mathbb{R}$, I want to know if the following parabolic equation gets a smooth and unique solution
\begin{align}
&v_t-\mathcal{L}v=f,\quad (t,x)\in(0,T]\times\mathbb{R},\\
&v(0,x)=g(x).\quad x\in \mathbb{R}.
\end{align}
where $f$ and $g$ are smooth and satisfy $|f|+|g|\leq A\exp(Ax^2)$ for some $A>0$.